# Custom Identity EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-identity

I'm trying customize EntityFrameworkCore Identity with AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles only... Is it possible?

My code:

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>, int>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        //base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<IdentityUser<int>>().ForSqlServerToTable("AspNetUsers")
            //.Ignore(x => x.Claims)
            //.Ignore(x => x.Logins)
            .HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.Entity<IdentityRole<int>>().ForSqlServerToTable("AspNetRoles")
            //.Ignore(x => x.Claims)
           .HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>().ForSqlServerToTable("AspNetUserRoles")
            .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });

        builder.Ignore<IdentityUserLogin<int>>();
        builder.Ignore<IdentityUserToken<int>>();
        builder.Ignore<IdentityUserClaim<int>>();
        builder.Ignore<IdentityRoleClaim<int>>();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
          ...
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            ...
        }
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ...
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

**CreateAsync** = success, but **SignInAsync** return *InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUserClaim`1' because this type is not included in the model for the context.*

My database contains only tables AspNetRoles, AspNetUsers and AspNetUserRoles with default columns(Id's type int).

Thanks.

Comment: Why the extra 4 lines to ignore `IdentityUserClaim` etc?

Comment: Ignore IdentityUserLogin != InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserLogin<int>' requires a key to be defined.

Comment: Without extra lines returns -> IdentityUserLogin<int> requires a key to be defined.  IdentityUserToken<int> requires a key to be defined.  SqlException: Invalid object name 'UserClaims'. SqlException: Invalid object name 'RolerClaims'.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution ?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/912#issuecomment-233471596

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but I had created an inherited XXXRole. The error was: Cannot create a DbSet for 'XXXRole' because this type is not included in the model for the context.

It turns out I needed to also let the AppDbContext know which role was being used, otherwise it assumes...

So I added it to the generic type for IdentityDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<XXXUser, XXXRole, string>
{
....
}
```

In this case above, I suggest you make a new concrete class inheriting from "IdentityRole". Then you would do something like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<XXXUser, XXXRole, int>
{
....
}
```

I believe the same data type of key is used for both Users and Roles - so you may also need to create XXXUser : IdentityUser

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem, and even thou my mistake was stupid it could help someone in the future:

I had named

`public class IdentityDbContext: IdentityDbContext<User>
{
....
}`

And when I referenced it I did not specify from what namespace it should take `IdentityDbContext` (*the correct was `MyNamespace.IdentityDbContext` (doh!)  )

Comment: That's because you should not give your classes the same name as the one you are inheriting from.